# Filtering a list of processes based on a list of string objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of string objects which represent process names. I want to filter a collection of running Processes (retrieved by using GetProcesses()), by using the list of string objects I have. So if I want to look for the Sql Server process running in the processes collection, I will look for the string name as stored in the string list.

How can I filter a list of processes to get only the processes which have the same process names as a list of strings (the different generic types makes it hard - for me, anyway)?

I am using .NET 4.0 and LINQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it..

```
var targetNames = new [] { "processone", "Processtwo" };

var processes = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                where targetNames.Any(n => n == p.ProcessName)
                select p;
```

Comment: Close. ProcessName will not include ".exe" so the `targetNames` shouldn't. If the OP isn't using the proper case the comparison should be case-insensitive: `n => n.Equals(p.ProcessName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: .Intersect() would be a better choice than .Any() here.