# How can I filter out certain processes from the process list in list box C#

Tags: c#, process, listbox

Hello I would like to know how I could filter out certain processes so they do not appear inside of my list box in C# he is the code that I am currently using for the process list

```
        {
            Process[] allProc = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in allProc)
            {
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What processes do you want to filter? Just use an if statement with your filter condition before you add them to the list.

Comment: Perhaps some kind of `if` statement to determine whether or not you should add the process to the list?

Comment: i want to filter out the svchost and some other ones

Comment: i just started learning C# about 1week ago so I don't know some of this stuff

Comment: FYI [If statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) and [LINQ where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: I found [this ten year old post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304326/1070452) simply by feeding your title to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this (Before add LINQ namespace in `using System.Linq;`)

```
{
            string[] excludeProcesses = {"ARRAY OF PROCESS NAMES TO EXCLUDE"};
            Process[] allProc = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in allProc)
            {
            if !((excludeProcesses.Contains(p.ProcessName)))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: how do i use the array of processes

Comment: @Jack Put the process names you want to exclude in? For example "svchost.exe".

Comment: `listBox1.Items.AddRange(Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName != "processname" || p.ProcessName != "someotherProcessName").Select(p => p.ProcessName).ToArray());` why not filter the processes out you don't need first?

Comment: Thank you for this help I am done with this Question!