# Problem Process.GetProcesses Not work with 2 same processes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I use Process.GetProcesses(); I should get all local processes displayed or?
My problem is that I wanted to have all "engine" processes called. For this I started the program 2x but in my list box I get it only once.
can someone tell me why?
Attached is a screenshot of the code and task manager with the 2x "Engine".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
        
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
        {
            string Prozess = Convert.ToString(localAll[i]);
            bool b = Prozess.Contains(textBox1.Text);
            if (b)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Prozess);
            }
        }

        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Greetings

Tim

[image: Screenshot of it]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a list of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304326/filtering-a-list-of-processes-based-on-a-list-of-string-objects) and [Get processes by a part of name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632162/c-sharp-killing-a-process-by-a-part-of-its-name/14632298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the main question, the reason is probably in `i <= 49` condition.
Retrieved list for processes by `Process.GetProcesses()` isn't sorted, so processes in it positioned randomly and first 50 elements may not include your second/third/N instances of a process or even specified one.
You should check entire list instead of only 50.

Also,
Your `localAll[i]` is an object of `Process`, which contains `ProcessName`
property (and other info about running process). You trying to check whether `an object` of `Process` in its string representaion (by `Convert.ToString()`) (which giving you `System.Diagnostics.Process (ProcessName)` type name) contains a string value from your `textBox1`.

```
string someInput = textBox1.Text;

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

// Try also change i <= 49 to a collection.Count/Length, 
// because received by Process.GetProcesses() list of processes
// isn't sorted and your duplicated processes may not be included
// in first 50 elements.
for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; ++i) // or foreach (Process p in processes) ...
{                
    string processName = processes[i].ProcessName    
    // Do whatever you wish with processName

    if (processName.Contains(someInput))
    {
        // listBox1.Items.Add(processName + ".exe");
        // ProcessName property doesn't include extension ".exe", 
        // only executable binary name.
    }
}
```

Or simply with `System.Linq` extensions:

```
string[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().
                     Where(x => x.ProcessName.Contains(textBox1.Text)). // Take care about case-sensivity of comparsion
                     Select(x => x.ProcessName + ".exe").
                     ToArray();
// Where extension will filtrate all running processes
// by checking its ProcessName properties for containing
// your specified input value in textBox1
// Select extension will retrieve only process names
// from filtrated Process objects collection as strings, 
// which you can convert to an array of strings.

// Simply append all filtrated string collection to your ListBox by AddRange.
listBox1.Items.AddRange(processes);
```